# Adding object to a ArrayList in a correct index using for-loop

Tags: java, arraylist, addition

I have a method to add a patient to the correct index depending on their priority. However it seems that when I add more than one person, it doesn't get added. I'm not too sure what I'm missing in my add method. My guess is there is something wrong with the if-else statement but I'm not able to pinpoint where the problem is.

```
public void addPatient(Patient sickPerson)
{
    int lim = patients.size();

    if (patients.isEmpty()) //if empty
    {
        patients.add(sickPerson);
    }
    else //if not empty
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lim; i++) 
        {
        if (patients.get(i).compareTo(sickPerson) > 0) 
            // if the sickperson is more important...
            {
                patients.add(i, sickPerson);
            } 

        else if (patients.get(i).compareTo(sickPerson) == 0)
            // if the sickperson's priority is the same, 
            {
                patients.add(i + 1, sickPerson);
            }
        else 
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

}

@Test
public void getNumWaitingTest() {

    WaitingRoom a = new WaitingRoom();
    Patient b = new Patient("name", "bad", 1, 1);
    Patient c = new Patient("name2", "bad2", 2, 2);

    a.addPatient(b);
    a.addPatient(c);

    assertEquals(2, a.getNumWaiting());
}
```

and if I run this test case, I would get 1 for the numWaiting for some reason...
where could I have gone wrong in this code??

Answer (score 2):

After the `for` cycle you are not adding any patient if they have lower priority than the existing ones.

As soon as you add a patient in the list you should `return` from the method; if you reach the end of the method it means that the new patient has the lowest priority and you should add him at the end of the list.